# Access single value of a mapped struct

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I want to access a single value of a mapped struct from another contract. For now, I know how to return all values of the struct by using the following code:

```
function getUnitById(uint256 _id) public view returns (uint256 id, string name, uint256 attack, uint256 defense, uint256 heal, uint256[] questsCompleted) {
    return unitsContract.tokenToUnit(_id);
}
```

but what do I have to do to access only one single value?

```
return unitsContract.tokenToUnit(_id).questsCompleted;
```

would make sense in my opinion but that does not work at all.

Did anyone get a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible till solidity version 0.4.24.

You are calling a function`unitsContract.tokenToUnit(_id)` whose returun type is `tuple`.

You are not accessing `mapping` and therefore it is not possible to get a particular attribute using `unitsContract.tokenToUnit(_id).questsCompleted`.